# How to decode string as JSON

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to download a JSON stringand assigning it to a `TextArea`:

```
private async void KliknijMnie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://someurl.with?parameters=inURL");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<uzytkownika>(responseBody);
        this.DataContext = root1;

        //fileName.Text = root1;
    }
    catch
    {
        string responseBody = "some errors";
    }
    finally
    {
        ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

class 'uzytkownika':

```
public class Day1
{
    public int @int { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public object text { get; set; }
    public string czas { get; set; }
    public bool funkcje { get; set; }
}

public class Day2
{
    public int @int { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public object text { get; set; }
    public string czas { get; set; }
    public bool funkcje { get; set; }
}

public class Day3
{
    public int @int { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public object text { get; set; }
    public string czas { get; set; }
    public bool funkcje { get; set; }
}

(....)

public class Day30
{
    public int @int { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public object text { get; set; }
    public string czas { get; set; }
    public bool funkcje { get; set; }
}

public class Grafik
{
    public Day1 day1 { get; set; }
    public Day2 day2 { get; set; }
    public Day3 day3 { get; set; }
    (....)
    public Day30 day30 { get; set; }
}

public class uzytkownika
{
    public string imie { get; set; }
    public string nazwisko { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string miesiacTXT { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdate { get; set; }
    public string updatedBy { get; set; }
    public Grafik grafik { get; set; }
}
```

And grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Button Name="KliknijMnie" Margin="10,10,254,507" Click="KliknijMnie_Click">pobierz dane</Button>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,143,0,10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Width="200" Text="First name"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding imie}" Width="230"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,143,0,10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Width="200" Text="LastName"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding nazwisko}" Width="230"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

What's wrong? Why is `root1` not assigned to `textblock`?

Comment: Your class is completely wrong.  It needs to match the JSON.

Comment: Please, don't name your methods, variables, classes or controls in Polish...

Comment: I suggest you to do the simplest thing possible, use Json.net (a free library). I want to suggest you this [nice site](http://json2csharp.com) that create the output c# class from a Json string as it may be pretty useful if you decide to not use Json.net.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini, I see `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` in the code, which I think means he already has Json.net.

Comment: @gunr2171 whoops, my bad

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code as reference. Suppose you need to display the username  in your textblock using facebook graph API

```
private void KliknijMnie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://graph.facebook.com/stackoverflow"));
    }

    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
                this.DataContext = root1;
       }
    }
 }
```

and json parser class (RootObject.cs) file should be like this, you can also use json2csharp.com for creating further json parser classes. All parsed data is been stored in root1 you can further create reference to same.

```
public class Location
{
public string street { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public string state { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public string zip { get; set; }
}

public class Cover
{
public long cover_id { get; set; }
public string source { get; set; }
public int offset_y { get; set; }
public int offset_x { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public string about { get; set; }
public string category { get; set; }
public string founded { get; set; }
public bool is_published { get; set; }
public Location location { get; set; }
public string mission { get; set; }
public string phone { get; set; }
public int talking_about_count { get; set; }
public string username { get; set; }
public int were_here_count { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string link { get; set; }
public int likes { get; set; }
public Cover cover { get; set; }
}
```

In your xmal you have

```
  <TextBlock Name="usernamebox" Text="{Binding username}"></TextBlock>
```

now to assign json object value to textblock you can

```
this.usernamebox.DataContext = root1.username;
```

Comment: Ok, my example above works fine after changeing class. Now I change json source and class (with json2csharp.com) and it won't work. I've got this errors: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
Can you help me, please?

Comment: catch returns this error 'ERROR! : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'. I'm new in c# and I don't know how to start to fix this issue

Comment: Check following things: 1) The text block you are binding should match exactly same to the json object in your class. 2) check for the response that you are getting via your URI in your browser REST Client Plugin/add-on and printing the output in visual studio. It would give a brief idea how you could fix the issue.

Comment: Please Update your code so that we can guide you more specifically on your problem.